# Where to store the data for a GWT app - GAE data store or XML file

Tags: java, xml, google-app-engine, gwt, google-cloud-datastore

I have a GWT app which is deployed on GAE. One part of my application relies on static data, which is currently stored in an XML file. The application reads this data into a collection of POJOs. The data is sent over to the client using GWT-RPC. Based on the selections made by the user, it applies filters to the collection to get specific objects (the filtering is done on the client side).

The data may contain up to 3000 records, and the total XML file size would be around 1MB. There'll be no updates on this data from the application side (it's read-only), but I may be frequently adding new records or updating/fixing existing records during the initial few months (as the application evolves). The data has no relationship with any other data in the application.

One of my main consideration in fetch performance. I tried using Apache Digester to parse the XML, but noticed that even parsing 600 records and sending them to the client was a bit slow.

Given these requirements which of the following would be better and why - 1. Keep the data in the XML file, or 2. Store the data in the app engine data store?

Thanks.

Comment: So you always send the whole file to the client?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One alternative would be to load the XML file directly by GWT (without GWT-RPC and server parsing):

1. Use RequestBUilder to get the data from the server. Example usage: http://www.gwtapps.com/doc/html/com.google.gwt.http.client.html
2. Then use XMLParser to parse the reply. Example: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsXML.html#parsing

Here's an example combining both: http://www.roseindia.net/tutorials/gwt/retrieving-xml-data.shtml

The only downside is that you have to manually parse XML via DOM, where GWT-RPC directly produces objects.

**Update:**

based on the comments I'd recommend this:

1. Parse XML file with JAXB to create your objects: http://jaxb.java.net/guide/_XmlRootElement_and_unmarshalling.html
2. Save those to memcache: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/memcache/overview.html
3. On RPC request, check memcache, if data not there goto 1.

Comment: @Peter - thanks for your response. You might have figured that this question was a follow-up to one of my previous questions that you answered. The problem with RequestBuilder is that it exposes the entire XML (I can easily view the file using Firebug). I want to keep the XML protected from the user and expose it only through the application. If I send a collection of POJOs from the server, it doesn't expose the entire XML file to the users. Given this additional constraint, what would the best option? Thanks again.

Comment: Actually I didn't connect the two questions. You could still use GWT-RPC but send XML as one big string.

Comment: On AppEngine you can use JAXB to map XML to your classes and then store this classes (array or records?) to memcache.

Comment: @Peter - I tried your first suggestion and sent the XML file as string using GWT-RPC, but I can still pretty much read the file content in its entirety using Firebug. The only difference is that I see \n's and \t's in the output. I need to learn more about JAXB and memcache before I can try your second suggestion. I'll do that and post an update. Thanks.

Comment: @Peter - I've managed to replace Apache Digester with JAXB and the performance has improved. So, I'm good as far as XML parsing is concerned. Now coming to memcache, let's say I add new records to my XML file every week. How would I make sure that the object in the memcache is updated every time that the XML is updated? Thanks for all your help.

Comment: You could trigger the update by hand, via special URL or HTTP parameter. Or you could heve version embedded in XML file name: `data-314.xml`. If 314 is higher version then what you have in memcache, then reload.

Comment: @Peter - those are good suggestions but I'll prefer to avoid manual steps. I'm wondering whether it's possible to check the app's deployed date/time somehow. That would be something really unique even if I were to redeploy the same app version over and over again. I could store that date/time in a Memcache and when it changes I would flush the cache. Do you know if that's even possible? Thanks.

Comment: @Peter - I think SystemProperty.applicationVersion.get() is what I need. I'm going to give it a shot and get back. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The way I look at things, there are two bottle necks, though interrelated. One is loading the data (reading from XML, parsing). Another is sending it to the client.
Instead of sending the whole bunch, you might consider batch sending, like pagination.

Usually I prefer storing such files under WEB-INF.

Comment: You are right. I'm considering sending only filtered list of objects instead of sending everything, but the downside might be more client-server requests. But yeah, I'm certainly considering this option. Thanks.